# "ThisWorksheet" equivalent?

Tags: vba, excel

In Excel, I have some macros that are part of a *Worksheet* module.

In the code, I want to make sure that the ranges referred to are part of that worksheet.

For example, in my `Main Sheet` worksheet module, say I have:

```
Sub test()
Dim rng as Range
Set rng = Range("A1")
End Sub
```

Of course, I want to explicitly give the worksheet the range is on. Typically, I'd do

```
Set rng = Worksheets("Main Sheet").Range("A1")
```

But I'm curious, since I have my code in a worksheet module, how can I refer to that worksheet? I was thinking something like `ThisWorksheet` but that's not a method in VBA (but `ThisWorkbook` is, which is why I thought to try it).

My only other thoughts are that since my macro is inside a worksheet module, the "unassigned" range variable implicitly refers to the `Main Sheet` and **can not** refer to any other worksheet's cells.

Do I understand that correctly, or is there some way to refer to the worksheet the code running is stored in?

Comment: Since your code resides within the code module for your sheet, you can use the keyword Me to refer to that worksheet -- `Set rng = Me.Range("A1")`.  While not necessary, it does give you access to the IntelliSense.

Comment: @Domenic - Aha!  That seems like the answer, please feel free to create an answer and I can mark it.  (I also assume you *can not* use `Me` in a workbook module? Or if you can, `Me` then refers to essentially `ThisWorkbook`?).  WIthout `Me`, is my assumption correct in that there's an implicit reference to the worksheet with just `Range()`? Or could that still theoretically refer to another sheet if active?

Comment: @BruceWayne - In the `Workbook` module `Range()` will refer to whatever sheet is active, so you will need to be explicit if you need to be. If you are using any of the `Worksheet` events in the `Workbook` module, then you can use the `sh` variable that is passed from the event parameters.

Comment: `Me` refers to the *current object*, so if you're in the code-behind for `ThisWorkbook`, it refers to `ThisWorkbook` ;-)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A worksheet module is a *document module*, which is class just like any other, except it inherits (yes, *inherits*, as in *class inheritance*!) members from the `Worksheet` interface, and being a *document module* the only way to create an instance of it is through the host application's object model (i.e. `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add` is essentially a *factory method*).

Being a class module, the worksheet object for that module is an *instance* of, say, the `Sheet1` class, which contains whatever members you put into it, *plus* every member inherited from the `Worksheet` interface... **including** a `Range` property.

So the reason why an unqualified `Range` call in a worksheet module refers to *that* sheet, is simply because of the VBA language's scoping rules - given this code:

```
foo = Range("B12").Value2
```

1. If there's a local variable in that scope named `Range`, then that's what `Range` refers to.
2. **If there's a member in that module named `Range`, then that's what `Range` refers to.**
3. If there's a global variable in the current project named `Range`, then that's what `Range` refers to.
4. If there's a globally-scoped identifier in a referenced project or type library named `Range`, then that's what `Range` refers to.

[image: Members of 'Sheet1' include a 'Range' property, which is a member of the 'Worksheet' class]

You can disambiguate the `Range` call by qualifying it with the `Me` keyword, which returns a reference to the current object, in this case through the `Sheet1` interface (still assuming you're in the code-behind of `Sheet1`):

```
foo = Me.Range("B12").Value2
```

That code will work against `Sheet1` if you're in the code-behind of `Sheet1`, and against `Sheet2` if you're in the code-behind of `Sheet2`, ...and will fail to compile in a standard module.

But the nature and implications of `Me` deserve more attention.

---

#### About 'Me'

`Me` is a *reserved name* (you can't have a variable by that name) that refers to something that can only exist at run-time in a procedure's scope: the *current object*. Under the hood, when you make a member call to `DoSomething` against a `Class1` object, the call goes essentially like this:

```
Set obj = New Class1
Class1.DoSomething obj
```

This means `DoSomething` looks like this in VBA:

```
Public Sub DoSomething()
End Sub
```

But VBA sees it like this:

```
Public Sub DoSomething(ByVal Me As Class1)
End Sub
```

That makes `Me` an implicit locally-scoped `ByVal` parameter of type `Class1`, and inside the `DoSomething` scope it holds a reference to whatever object *the caller* is currently using.

That's basically the crux of my [Understanding 'Me' (no flowers, no bees)](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2018/09/05/understanding-me-no-flowers-no-bees/) article =)

<sub>([relevant language spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/microsoft_general_purpose_programming_languages/ms-vbal/78bcb344-4966-4401-bb55-72729790ebee?redirectedfrom=MSDN))</sub>

---

When you're in a *standard module*, an unqualified `Range` call obeys the exact same scoping rules:

1. If there's a local variable in that scope named `Range`, then that's what `Range` refers to.
2. If there's a member in that module named `Range`, then that's what `Range` refers to.
3. If there's a global variable in the current project named `Range`, then that's what `Range` refers to.
4. **If there's a globally-scoped identifier in a referenced project or type library named `Range`, then that's what `Range` refers to.**

(assuming no *shadowing* of the `Range` identifier is occurring in that module/project)

The globally-scoped identifier in this case can be found in the hidden `Global` module:

[image: members of '_Global' include a 'Range' property]

Comment: Whooooo!!! That's an awesome answer, thank so very much for your help and time taken to write it!

Comment: This is one big reason why I dislike implicit references - they don't help in [making wrong code look wrong](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2005/05/11/making-wrong-code-look-wrong/). Consistently qualifying with `Me` for all member accesses will scream wrong when transposing that code into a standard module or in an incompatible class/document class and paves the way for easy refactoring.

Comment: (Oh, PS I use RubberDuck all the time, it's great! Thanks so much for your most excellent work on it!! :D)

Comment: @BruceWayne oh, I just write the bugs - blame [this](https://stackoverflow.com/users/643342/this), [M.Doerner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5536802/m-doerner), [Comintern](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4088852/comintern), [Vogel612](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1803692/vogel612), [ThunderFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5757159/thunderframe) and everyone else involved for the bits that *do* work ;-) (thanks!)