# Application.Cells VS Application.ActiveSheet.Cells

Tags: vba, excel, cells, vbe

The Macro Recorder generated the following statement:

```
Cells.Select
```

Now I understand that without the object qualifier this will return all the cells as a `Range` object.

However, I am wondering what the fully qualified version of this statement is?

Is it:

1. `Application.Cells.Select`
2. `Application.ActiveSheet.Cells`
3. `Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells`

In other words, which one of those fully qualified statements is actually executed by VBE when it runs `Cells.Select`?

What is the difference between all of these??? As all of these access the same object in the end - is it just personal preference as to which statement I would use if I wanted to explicitly qualify all the objects?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Avoid Select, it is not needed in VBA very often.  Avoid Activesheet, unless you are in a single sheet workbook and are just moving quickly.  Cells would normally mean a single Cell, Range for Range, they have some different methods.  Cells is often used inside of a Range specification, especially when variables are used to step through rows and/or columns.  Better to name the worksheet in developer tab-properties and call it directly (ex. wsMySheet.Cells (x,y).Value = wsMyOtherSheet.Cells(x,y).Value) x and y being loop variables of double or long for instance.

Comment: Probably active sheet, it will always need an object defined.  But as I said above, I would avoid its usage if possible or it will lead to some hard to track errors.  Always let VBE know what workbook and what sheet you are using.  Common practice for those that start opening workbooks and copying info and then closing them, you never want to leave it in doubt or the Application will not be able to resolve the object you wish to work with, usually throws and error, might just give strange results.

Comment: This would be the most fully qualified, it has the least amount of ambiguity for the "compiler" to fill in: Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells

Comment: Wookies-Will-Code - thank you for all those tips! I wrote them all down so I can remember for the future. :D

Comment: @Wookies-Will-Code except `ActiveSheet.Parent` will always point to `ActiveWorkbook`, so qualifying `ActiveSheet` is always redundant - VBA doesn't need to work "harder" to know what sheet it's referring to, it *already* has the reference. Hence, any worksheet-qualified member call is sufficiently qualified to be perfectly unambiguous - qualifying all the way up to `Application` **is** useful though, but in scenarios where you own the `Application` instance (e.g. Excel automation, from Word). In fact, implicit `Application` refs can cause "ghost process" and bad teardown in these cases.

Answer (score 6):

It's complicated :)

> *As all of these access the same object in the end*

True. Keywords "in the end". The difference is *how many steps it takes to get there*...

Unqualified `Cells` (or `Range`, `Rows`, `Columns`, `Names`, etc.) aren't magic, they're member calls (`Property Get`) against a hidden, global-scope object cleverly named `Global`:

[image: object browser: members of 'Global']

You can validate that this hidden object is involved, by blowing up in a standard module:

```
Sub GoesBoom()
    'throws error 1004 "Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed"
    Debug.Print Range(Sheet2.Cells(1, 1), Sheet3.Cells(1, 1))
End Sub
```

`_Global` and `Global` are closely related - without diving deep into COM, you can consider `Global` the class, and `_Global` its interface (it's not really quite like that though - look into "COM coClasses" for more information).

But `Cells` is a property of the `Range` class:

[image: object browser: members of 'Range']

I *think* it's reasonable to presume that `Global` calls are pretty much all redirected to `Application`, which exposes all members of `Global`, and then some.

Now as you noted, `Application` also have a `Cells` property - but `Cells` belong on a `Worksheet`, so no matter what we do, we need to end up with a `Worksheet` qualifier... and then any worksheet belongs in a `Worksheets` collection, which belongs in a `Workbook` object - so we can infer that an unqualified `Cells` call would be, in fully-explicit notation, equivalent to... (drumroll):

```
Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells
```

But you don't need to be *that* explicit, because `ActiveSheet` has a `Parent` that is always going to be the `ActiveWorkbook`, so this is also explicit, without going overboard:

```
ActiveSheet.Cells
```

But that's all assuming global context. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51753167/1188513) explains everything about it - the gist of it, is that if you're in a worksheet's code-behind, then an unqualified `Cells` member call isn't `Global.Cells`, but `Me.Cells`.

---

Now, note that `Cells` returns a `Range`. Thus, whenever you invoke it against a `Range` without providing parameters, you're making a redundant member call:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B10").Cells ' parameterless Range.Cells is redundant
```

Comment: You weren't kidding when you said it was complicated. When I learn more (because I just started a week ago) I will come back to this to see if I understand your answer better. I got about 50% of it though. lol Thanks for the response! :)

Comment: I was wondering for a while why you were seeing a _Global object in the object browser (F2) which I didn't. It turned out I had to enable "Show Hidden Members" (right mouse click). Maybe this info is useful to someone.

Answer (score 2):

Let's take the post apart:

> ```
> Cells.Select
> ```
>
> Now I understand that without the object qualifier this will return
>   all the cells as a Range object.

That's actually somewhat incorrect. While it is true that `.Cells` returns a `Range.Cells` object which returns all the cells, `Cells.Select` is actually a method of the `Range` object which - *as you may have guessed* - `Select`s the range (in our case, all the cells)

The `Select` method, as per [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.Select) **actually returns a `Variant`** and not a `Range` object.
 That it is a pretty important distinction to make, especially if you plan on passing that value to anything. So if we pretended to be a compiler

1. `Cells` -> `ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range.Cells` returns `Range` of all the cells
2. `Range.Cells.Select` -> first we take our returned `Range`, we  then select the cells in Worksheet and actually return  a `Variant` (not `Range`)

As to the other part of the question. It depends where your module is placed. By default, `Cells` is shorthand for the following statement:

```
Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range.Cells
```

This however is subject to change depending on where your module is placed and if Application, workbook or sheet has been modified.

---

In general, it is a good coding practice to always specify at least a specific `Worksheet` object whenever you're referencing a `Range`, eg.

```
 Sheets("Sheet1").Range.Cells
```

This is **explicit and therefore less error prone and clearer to comprehend, be it for you or anyone working with your code.**. You always know what exactly you're working with and not leave it to guesswork.

Obviously, the moment you start working with multiple workbooks, it's a good idea to incorporate `Workbook` objects statements before the `Sheet`. You get my point.

---

Last but not least, whatever you're trying to do, it's probably for the best you avoid using `Select`. It's generally not worth it and prone to unexpected behaviour.

Check this question here: [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: Rawrplus, thank you for your expeditious and informative answer. That clarified a lot for me!!!!

Comment: Rawrplus, one more question: Cells is a property of quite a few objects. How do I know which one the compiler is using if the object qualifiers are missing from the statement? I think that's what drives me most insane.

Comment: @GeekyFreaky you don't. not without peeking at the source code. but you can infer it.

Comment: I upvoted this answer too early - `ThisWorkbook` has nothing to do here, it's `ActiveWorkbook`; `ThisWorkbook` refers to *the code that contains the VBA project*, not the active workbook. Assuming otherwise can bite you.

Comment: anyway.. *avoid select and writing explicit code* in itself is upvote-worthy =)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon oops that is indeed correct. I have edited the answer now. That was my bad, somehow I got fixated on the `ThisWorkbook` in the original qeustion

Comment: @GeekyFreaky Mathieu basically answered that one for you. To put it in laymans terms, think of this like an onion. The outmost layer is the reference to the actual Cells and the deeper we go *the more layers we unpeel*  we need to manipulate with them. That's why I recommended to always declare specific `Worksheet` when refering to range. So we know with which layer we're always referring to and not leave it to presumptions. The innermost layer - the core - is indded the `Application`  itself *(that's not exactly correct, as Mathieu's answer points out, but as a simplified example it goes...)*

Comment: @MathieuGuindon  - I just figured that out now and came back to correct it! hahahaha You beat me to the chase. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you just type `Cells` - in and of itself it does nothing. It is the same as `Range.Cells`. The only advantage of `Cells` is that it can accept numeric value for column (second argument). It's very handy when you do complex manipulations.

`Range.Cells` just returns `Range` object. When you have `Range` object, think of it as a small Excel worksheet. Say, you have range `Range("F3:J10")`. Then following ranges all refer to `H3` cell:

1. `Range("F3:J10").Cells(3)`
2. `Range("F3:J10")(3)`
3. `Range("F3:J10").Cells(1, 3)`
4. `Range("F3:J10")(1, 3)`
5. `Range("F3:J10").Cells(1, "C")`
6. `Range("F3:J10")(1, "C")`
7. `Range("F3:J10").Range("C1")`