# What about "Application" as default object in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-365

I have just written this easy macro in Excel VBA for merging a group of selected cells:

```
Sub Macro_Merge()
Dim Temp As String
Dim S As Variant

Temp = ""
For Each S In Selection
  If Temp = "" Then
    Temp = CStr(S.Value)
  Else:
    Temp = Temp + "," + CStr(S.Value)
  End If
Next

Selection.Merge
Selection.Value = Temp
Selection.VerticalAlignment = xlTop
  
End Sub
```

This works fine, but I always see that annoying dialog box, warning me about loosing data while merging (which is exactly what I'm trying to avoid in my macro).

I can get rid of that dialog box, configuration the `Application`'s `DisplayAlerts` property:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Selection.Merge
Selection.Value = Temp
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

This is working fine.
So, as `Application` is the default object, I tried to clean up my code, as follows:

```
DisplayAlerts = False
Selection.Merge
Selection.Value = Temp
DisplayAlerts = True
```

As you see, I simply omit mentioning the `Application` object. This is something which is allowed and I've done in the past. (If not in VBA, then Delphi, maybe?)

... but to my surprise, the dialog box appears again (although pressing F1 brings me to [the official "Application.DisplayAlerts" documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.displayalerts?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm133119);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)).
This leaves me with a simple question:

If a simple `DisplayAlerts = ...` does not equal `Application.DisplayAlerts = ...` anymore, what does it mean and how can I use it?

For your information, I'm working with Excel-365.

Comment: If you will have `Option Explicit` on tot of the module where the code runs, it will warn you that `DisplayAlerts` variable is not defined... Otherwise, VBA neglects it and acts as it does not exist.

Comment: @FaneDuru: you seem to be right: VBA does not recognise `DisplayAlerts` as being a property of the `Application` object. However, I'm sure I've worked with a programming language where it was allowed to omit the `Application` object. Delphi, maybe?

Comment: @FaneDuru: you can add your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: No, thanks... It should be more complex for an answer. In VBA, `Application` also exposes some properties/methods directly: `WorksheetFunction`, `ActiveSheet`, `ActiveCell`, `ActivePrinter` and much more, but not all of them...

Comment: @FaneDuru: too late, you've been beaten by [BigBen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9245853/bigben) :-)

Comment: @ BigBen `Debug.Print ActivePrinter` correctly returns the active printer name, port included. At least, on 365...

Comment: In Delphi you only don't need to use the object instance variable when you use a ```with``` block! Besides that is your question absolutely not related to Delphi.

Comment: There are some cased of methods which behaves differently when using them with `Application` or with `Application.WorksheetFunction`. For instance, declaring `Dim mtch` followed by `mtch = Application.WorksheetFunction.match(5, arr, 0)` will return a fatal error if 5 is not found in `arr`. But `mtch = Application.match(5, arr, 0)` does not. In this way you may check `If IsError(mtch) Then` and have the answer about its existence in the array or not...

Comment: I do  not have a problem being beaten... :)

Comment: @FaneDuru: keep out: you're talking about dropping the `WorksheetFunction` property, I was only talking about dropping the `Application` object reference. Those are complete different things. (But I do understand how confusing this appears to be :-) )

Comment: I know what you asked for, but I only wanted to emphasize that there are `Application` methods, even not shown by intellisense, but exposed and which acts differently than its function (`WorksheetFunction`). Try writing `Application.mat` and see if `Match` is suggested... Of course, this was  not required in your question.

Comment: I removed the Delphi tag as that was only a speculative but non valid connection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DisplayAlerts` is an undeclared variable.

Certain `Application` properties and methods can (effectively) have the `Application` omitted:

- `ActiveCell`, `ActiveSheet`, `ActiveWorkbook`, `ActiveWindow`, `Addins`, `Charts`, `Selection`, etc.
- `Calculate`, `Evaluate`, `Intersect`, `Run`, `Union`, etc.

(but see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70973481/9245853) why/how this works):

A boolean property such as `DisplayAlerts` (`EnableEvents`, `ScreenUpdating`, etc) doesn't fall into the above category.

A golden rule in order not to fall into such a trap is the usage of `Option Explicit` while writing macros.

Answer (score 7):

Just to add some information to the answer of @BigBen. If you write something like `Workbooks` or `ActiveSheet` in your code, VBA is not looking into the `Application`-object - it is looking into a (rather well hidden) object named `Global`.

The global object is exposing some (but not all) properties and methods of the `Application`-object, so `ActiveSheet` is referring to `Application.ActiveSheet` - but not because the `Application` has a member with this name but because the Global object defines that `ActiveSheet` means `Application.ActiveSheet`. In fact even the `Application`-object is accessed via the Global object.

There is hardly any information about this Global object or its concept. I found a page from [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.global) describing the Global object of MS Word, but the only explanation there is *"Contains top-level properties and methods that don't need to be preceded by the Application property."*. For Excel, I found [this page](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/programming-excel-with/0596007663/ch04s08.html) on O'Reilly.

From time to time you get strange error messages like *"Excel VBA Method 'Range' of object'_global' failed"* - this is a pointer to the Global object. I would be glad to learn more about the concepts and mechanics of this object, but I am afraid that there are only very few people around that know more (except of course Mathieu Guindon AKA Mr. Rubberduck...). In daily life, we take it for granted that things like `ActiveSheet` simply works.

Comment: Just wanted to check if someone is reading this ;-) - corrected. I know why I always preach to use `Option Explicit`...

Comment: Though not covering exactly the question in OP, the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51897030/application-cells-vs-application-activesheet-cells/51898006?r=SearchResults&s=1|26.7330#51898006) describing how *member calls (Property Get) against a hidden, global-scope object cleverly named Global* work and might give further insight