# Why am I getting a "Script out of range" error while running the vba code for "For Loop" to copy data?

Tags: excel, vba

```vb
Sub GenerateProductionReport()
    '*Let’s define the variables*    
    Dim GCell As Range
    Dim Txt$, MyPath$, MyWB$, MySheet$
    Dim myValue As Integer
    Dim Number As Integer
    Dim cmdprodhrsreport As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim r As Long
    Dim LastRowRpt As Long
    
    '*Search what*
    MyPath = "\\Mypath\xxx\xxx\xxx\"
    
    '*The name of the workbook to be searched*
    MyWB = "Daily Data Tracker.xlsx"
    
    Workbooks.Open FileName:=MyPath & MyWB
    LastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    '*Use the current sheet to store the found data*
    For r = 2 To LastRow 'In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & r).Value = Adminaccess.txtstartdate.Value Then'problem here for next r
             Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & r & ":G" & r & ",K" & r & ":Q" & r).Copy

            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Production").Activate
            '*Range("A2:K99999").ClearContents*
            MySheet = ActiveSheet.Name 
            '*Range("A2:K99999").ClearContents*
    
            LastRowRpt = Worksheets("Production").Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    
            Worksheets("Production").Range("A" & LastRowRpt + 1).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
        End If
    Next r
    
    'ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").SetFocus
     
    '*Close data workbook; don’t save it; turn screen updating back on*
    ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: I am generating a report from one workbook with date search criteria and copying the found values to another workbook but while doing so for the first r it copies the row for the corresponding date but for the next r , it shows the error, Please help.

Comment: What `Adminaccess` is? A form? Does the error appear on this line `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & r & ":G" & r & ",K" & r & ":Q" & r).Copy`?

Comment: `Worksheets` is `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets`, as opposed to `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets`. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/11683, save the result of `Workbooks.Open()` into a variable and use it refer to the opened workbook unambiguously.

Comment: Activating `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Production").Activate` in the loop, at next iteration `Worksheets("Sheet1")` will belong to `ThisWorkbook`. To be the one belonging to `MyWB`, like I suppose, you must use at the beginning of the code: `Dim sh1 as Worksheet` and after `MyWB` opening `Set sh1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")` `LastRow = sh1.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row`. Then, change the problematic line in `sh1.Range("D" & r & ":G" & r & ",K" & r & ":Q" & r).Copy`.

Comment: Adminacess is a Userform @FaneDuru and the problem is in the upper line of the code you mentioned

Comment: Thankyou @FaneDuru , your code solved the problem. Now it is working fine.

Comment: Glad I could help! I will transform it in an answer. If I will be able to do kit on my mobile phone...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Production").Activate` in the loop, at next iteration `Worksheets("Sheet1")` will belong to `ThisWorkbook`.

To be/remain the one belonging to `MyWB`, like I suppose, you must use at the beginning of the code:

`Dim sh1 as Worksheet`

and after `MyWB` opening `Set sh1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")`

followed by  `LastRow = sh1.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row`.

Then, change the problematic line in

`sh1.Range("D" & r & ":G" & r & ",K" & r & ":Q" & r).Copy`

Answer (score 1):

"Subcript out of range" (run-time error 9) is a common error that means you're trying to retrieve an item from an array or collection, using a subscript that doesn't exist in that array/collection.

```
Dim things(0 To 9) As Long
things(10) = 42 '<~ "subscript out of range"
```

The Excel object model raises that error when you try to retrieve a `Worksheet` from a `Sheets` collection by name, but the specified sheet doesn't exist in the supplied `Sheets` collection.

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("boom") '<~ if sheet is not in ActiveWorkbook sheets, error 9 is raised.
```

The trick is to always be explicit about what objects belong to what. For example:

> ```
> Workbooks.Open FileName:=MyPath & MyWB
> LastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
> ```

Here we're explicit about what `Worksheet` this `Range` call should work with (but `Rows` is implicitly qualified with the `ActiveSheet`), but the `Worksheets` collection is implicitly referring to whatever the `ActiveWorkbook` is. That works, because by then we've *just* opened a workbook so that workbook must be active!

`Workbooks.Open` is a *function* that returns a reference to the opened `Workbook` object. Consider capturing that reference and removing the implicit reliance on the function's side-effects:

```
Dim book As Workbook
Set book = Application.Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyWB)
```

So here:

> ```
> '*Use the current sheet to store the found data*
> For r = 2 To LastRow 'In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
>     If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & r).Value = Adminaccess.txtstartdate.Value Then'problem here for next r
>          Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & r & ":G" & r & ",K" & r & ":Q" & r).Copy
> ```

If the *intent* is to iterate rows in `ThisWorkbook`, that's not what's happening here, because `If Worksheets("Sheet1")...` isn't explicit about what workbook it's working against, so if the `ActiveWorkbook` isn't `ThisWorkbook` and there's no worksheet named "Sheet1" in there, that throws error 9.

Unqualified, `Worksheets` refers to `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets` unless the code is written in the `ThisWorkbook` module (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51753167/1188513) for why).

So the simplest solution is to just qualify things:

```
'*Use the current sheet to store the found data*
For r = 2 To LastRow 'In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & r).Value = Adminaccess.txtstartdate.Value Then'problem here for next r
         ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & r & ":G" & r & ",K" & r & ":Q" & r).Copy
```

Now the code says what it does, and does what it says - without implicitly relying on side-effects and global state.

If "Sheet1" exists in `ThisWorkbook` at compile-time (`ThisWorkbook` is always the workbook that contains your VBA project), then you can use the sheet's `CodeName` to define a compile-time identifier that you can use as-is to refer to *that specific sheet* anywhere in the code - for example if you found the "Sheet1" in the VBE's *Project Explorer* and then explored its properties (F4), you could change its `(Name)` property from `Sheet1` to something meaningful.

Same with the "Production" sheet, could be just `ProductionSheet`, and then there's no need to dereference it from any `Sheets` collection anymore, it's just *there* waiting to be used.

Avoid implicit `ActiveWorkbook` references - the *real* solution is never to `Activate` anything; the solution is to stop implicitly qualifying member calls (i.e. `Worksheet` -> `someWorkbook.Worksheets`, `Range` -> `someSheet.Range`) that belong to an object.