# VBA range("A1") command not working when I open different excel workbook

Tags: excel, vba

My purpose is to copy rows from another Excel workbook and paste it back into my original Excel workbook

This code works perfectly well if i remove line 2 and test it on my original Excel workbook that i am working on.

But the moment i add in line 2 to activate another Excel workbook ("Book1"), and when i run the same code, this codes fails at the 3rd line. Error message is "Application-defined or object-defined error".
Strangely the first 2 lines works but until the 3rd line it fails. This only happens whenever i try to activate different excel workbook.

I tried to convert the Excel files into same format such as xlsm, xlsx, csv but it still does not work. I tried for hours. Please explain to me what is the error. Thank You

```
Sub test()

MsgBox ActiveCell.Value
Workbooks("Book1").Activate
Range("a1").End(xlDown).Select ----->>This line is where error occurs
i = ActiveCell.Row
Range(Rows(1), Rows(i)).Copy

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to specify which workbook `Rnage(A1")`? Use `Set` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put your `Sub Test()` inside a worksheet module, so the unqualified `Range("a1")` is resolved [against the sheet that contains this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10180412/11683), as opposed to the active sheet. You are thus [trying](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3902841/11683) to Select a range on a sheet that is not active.

If you put that code in a standard module, it would have worked because then the unqualified `Range` would have resolved [against the active sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51753167/11683).

The right thing to do is to qualify the `Range` calls and to [not select anything](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/11683):

```vb
MsgBox ActiveCell.Value
With Workbooks("Book1").Worksheets(1)
  .Range(.Range("A1"), .Range("A1").End(xlDown)).EntireRow.Copy
End With
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. It works well now once i change to standard module.

Answer (score 0):

To copy cells or entire ranges from one workbook to the other one, first try to define your variables:

```
Dim wb1 as Workbook, wb2 as Workbook
Dim sht1 as Worksheet, sht2 as Worksheet
set wb1 = Workbooks("Book1")
set wb2 = Workbooks("Book2")
set sht1 = wb1.sheets("YOUR_SHEET_BOOK1")
set sht2 = wb2.sheets("YOUR_SHEET_BOOK2")
```

You can then control them easily and make them equal.

```
With sht1
 sht2.range("A1:A10") = .range("A1:A10") 'range A1:A10 of sheet1 will be the same as sheet2
End with
```

Or with cells:

```
With sht1
 for i = 1 to 10
  sht2.cells(i, 1) = .cells(i, 1) 'does exactly the same
 Next
End with
```

It will be way faster than any copy you could make!

Comment: i get an error with this method. It says "object doesnt support this property or method"

Comment: Indeed, I forgot to put the sheet. I'll correct the answer.

Answer (score -2):

You need to specify on line 3 which workbook/worksheet you want to use.

Here are a couple options:

## Quick fix of your existing code

Since you are already activating the target workbook (instead of merely referring to it), you can just use `ActiveSheet` (short for `ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet`).

Try this:

```
Sub test()

MsgBox ActiveCell.Value
Workbooks("Book1").Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("a1").End(xlDown).Select
i = ActiveCell.Row
Range(Rows(1), Rows(i)).Copy

End Sub
```

## A quicker way

However, you could instead specify the range to copy without selecting or activating it. This is much quicker.

Try:

```
Sub test()

MsgBox ActiveCell.Value
Workbooks("Book1").Sheets(1).Range(Workbooks("Book1").Sheets(1).Range("A1"), Workbooks("Book1").Sheets(1).Range("A1").End(xlDown)).EntireRow.Copy

End Sub
```

Comment: I run into error at this command (.Range("A1"), .Range("A1").End(xlDown)). The error says "invalid or unqualified reference".

Is there any missing information?

Comment: I have edited the answer to fully qualify the range references for row and column aspects. This is overkill and can be done in a tidier fashion, but before tidying it up please try the edited solution and let us know how it went.