# VBA - Error Type mismatch in Worksheet_Change

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make a macro which detects when a cell changes to a value that I specify. It will then add, in another sheet of the same workbook, an extra row with the same format as the other rows. However, when I try to evaluate the value of the cell with the specified text string, I get an error that the types do not coincide.

I have tried to change the value of the cell to String but I still get the same error.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
Dim i As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D8:D312")) Is Nothing Then
    If Target.Value = "N.I.O" Then

        Worksheets("Desviaciones UB").Activate
        i = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        Rows(i).Copy
        Rows(i).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
        Rows(i).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
     End If
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: When `Target` is a multi-cell range, its `.Value` is a 2D array that can't be directly compared to a `String`.

Comment: You are probably thinking that after `Worksheets("Desviaciones UB").Activate` the `Rows(i)` will refer to the rows on that activated worksheet. It will however [still refer to this worksheet's `Rows`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64388116/11683), so you are copying the row into the worksheet that has the `Worksheet_Change`, thus triggering `Worksheet_Change` again, this time with the `Target` equal to the copied row. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/11683.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incorporating the feedback from the comments, which primarily means properly referencing the parent worksheet for each instance of `Range`, `Cells`, and `Rows`:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
    Set rng = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("D8:D312"))
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Desviaciones UB")

    For Each cell In rng
         If cell.Value = "N.I.O" Then
              Dim lastRow As Long
              lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
              
              ws.Rows(lastRow).Copy
              ws.Rows(lastRow + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
              ws.Rows(lastRow + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
              Application.CutCopyMode = False
         End If
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```